# get data from multiple element with the sample class using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one of the components label with the sample class tclick

```
<label class="btn btn-default tclick" data-tloc="value1" data-tkey="key1" >
<label class="btn btn-default tclick" data-tloc="value2" data-tkey="key2" >
<label class="btn btn-default tclick" data-tloc="value3" data-tkey="key3" >
```

Whenever click on any one component of label, class "checked" will be automatically added to label : 
ex:

```
<label class="btn btn-default tclick checked" data-tloc="value1" data-tkey="key1" >
<label class="btn btn-default tclick checked" data-tloc="value2" data-tkey="key2" >
```

but i want get exactly data-tloc, data-tkey when label is click ?
i like code jquery and I need one solution ?

Comment: How are you adding the class checked? Did you try using the same way you add to a label to get what you need from a label? *Hint:* `$(this).something`

Answer (score 4):

```js
$('label.tclick').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('checked');
  var tloc = $(this).data('tloc'),
      tkey = $(this).data('tkey');
  console.log(tloc, tkey);
});
```

```css
.checked { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<label class="tclick" data-tloc="value1" data-tkey="key1">Label1</label>
<label class="tclick" data-tloc="value2" data-tkey="key2">Label2</label>
<label class="tclick" data-tloc="value3" data-tkey="key3">Label3</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
$('label.tclick').click(function(){
    var tloc = $(this).data('tloc'),
        tkey = $(this).data('tkey');

    $(this).addClass('checked');

    console.log('Tloc:' + tloc + ', Tkey: ' + tkey);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After 'checked' is automatically added and you just want the data attributes on click then try on change because if click executes before the checked class is added is(':checked') may not work:

```
$( "label.tclick" ).on('change', function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    console.log($(this).data('tloc'));
    console.log($(this).data('tkey'));
  }
});
```

Comment: The question was pretty clear and this isn't what was asked for.

Comment: You are correct. I did not read the 'is click' part of the question clearly. Will make edits.

Comment: If you make edits, please make a significant improvement over the existing answers (via explanation, better code, etc). Duplicate answers only add clutter. (In some cases people post the same answer within a minute of one another, it's okay in those instances).

Comment: Okay. After reading the question, sounds like 'checked' class is not added via code so suggested posted an edited version.